# Radiant: "Archive Month Index"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, content-management-system, blogs, radiant

I trying to set up a simple blog with Radiant CMS and have a problem with the "Archive Month Index".
I set it up as it is described on this [weblog](http://radiantcms.org/blog/) but I just can't get it to work.

The Code is the the same as the guy in the video st using. It's:

```
<r:archive:children:each>
  <div class="blog-post">
    <h3><r:link /></h3>
    <p>
      <r:content />
    </p>
  </div>
</r:archive:children:each>
```

...for the Archive Index.

However when I go onto the post/2010/12 site (or any other date) I get that amazing

```
StandardTags::TagError in SiteController#show_page
Recursion error: already rendering the `body' part.
```

...instead of the Index Page for the month. I just can't think of how I am rendering the body part twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had exactly the same problem. So too do the default blog setups created by Radiant's installer.

The blog pages in Radiant looks something like:

```
+ Articles (Archive)
  |
  +- %B %Y Archives (Archive Month Index)
  |
  +- First Post
  | 
  +- Second Post
  |  
  +- Third Post
```

Everything under the Articles page seems to be included in the results returned by `<r:archive:children:each></r:archive:children:each>`.

This means that if the index page and the first post were created on Feb 02 2011, then the URL /articles/2011/02/ will throw this exception because the index page being processed to generate a page with a list of articles from Feb 2011 will recursively attempt to process itself.

The solution I wound up using is the `<r:unless_self></r:unless_self>` tags to winnow the page being processed (i.e. the index page) from the results of `<r:archive:children:each></r:archive:children:each>`.

An example non-crashing `body` page part for the index page would look something like this:

```
<r:archive:children:each order="desc">
  <r:unless_self>
    <div class="entry">
      <h3><r:link /></h3>
      <r:content />
    </div>
  </r:unless_self>
</r:archive:children:each>
```